# jquery ui autocomplete: remote source problem

Tags: json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Im using jquery UI autocomplete.

When i use a local variable as source everything works as it should.

```
var json = [{ value: "1", ... etc
...
source: json
```

But when i return the same source from another file, it doesnt work. I find the JSON object in firebug, but when i type

```
source: 'path/to/filethatreturnsjson...'
```

It doesnt work. Did i miss something? THanks

Comment: Do you have any code that can be seen? What file does return the json and so on. A little more information is needed!

Comment: Same problem - local JSON string works fine but with remote JSON its unable to perform context sensitive search as you type - it simply displays all the items in my case - no searching/filtering. @Tim - as Johan mentioned I've also verified that if we provide the JSON directly then its working fine (i.e. the search) but with remote url which returns exactly the same JSON - search won't work. Any help?